# How to check duplicate tweet using MGTwitterEngine

Tags: ios, twitter, mgtwitterengine

I use MGTwitterEngine in my iOS app.

I use this callback for check success posted my message.

```
- (void)requestSucceeded:(NSString *)connectionIdentifier
```

But how can I check if I alredy have posted my tweet and I don't want to duplicate it.

For example if I use iOS 5.0 in response I get UIAlertView:

**Cannot Send Tweet**

**The tweet, "bla bla bla" is a dupliacte and cannot be sent.**

How to create the same verification using MGTwitterEngine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to post a duplicate message, the Twitter API will respond with

```
403: Status is a duplicate.
```

Check the return status code and message, that will tell you if a tweet has been successful or not.

Comment: thanks for response but in this method I dont have any message